# Alert Dialog not shown on button press

Tags: flutter, dart

Class for Alert Dialog

```
class AlertWindow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const AlertWindow({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Builder(
        builder:(BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(this.title),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: new Text(
                      "OK"
                  )
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Its been called in a `aysnc` function like this

```
  Future<ParseUser> SignUP(username, pass, email) async {
    var user = ParseUser(username, pass, email);   // You can add columns to user object adding "..set(key,value)"
    var result = await user.create();
    if (result.success) {
      setState(() {
        _parseUser = user;     // Keep the user
      });
      print(user.objectId);
      new AlertWindow(
        title: "Signup success " + user.objectId,
      );
    } else {
      print(result.error.message);
      new AlertWindow(
        title: "Signup error " + result.error.message,
      );
    }
  }
```

on running this, I can see the `print` statements in the console, but the `AlertWindow` doesn't show up.

I've got a hunch that its probably got something to do with the parent `BuildContext` not been passed to the `AlertDialog` when I'm creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use function instead of using a widget 
Create a new function which return a future

```
      Future<dynamic> _showDialog(BuildContext context){
             return showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                     return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text(this.title),
                         actions: <Widget>[
                             new FlatButton(
                                 onPressed: (){
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                 },
                           child: new Text(
                                     "OK"
                            )
                         ),
                      ],
                  );
              }
          );
       }
```

Comment: How do I get access to `context` ? I'm calling the function `SignUP` inside a on pressed callback of a button. Which is being built in a build function of a `StatefulWidget`

Comment: Pass the context as parameter to function

Comment: should `Future<dynamic>` be `Future<void>`?

Comment: I think showDialog returns a Future<dynamic> I'm not sure try to use Future<void> if it works for you. But showDialog returns a Future<T> so dynamic will definitely works

Comment: Your code works and shows me the Alert dialog, just wondering why the original code did not work? Do you have any idea?

Comment: the original code didn't works showDailog returns showGeneralDialog and showGeneralDialog  use Navigator to push the route with some additional info check out the api reference below https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html   check this example also                  
 https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function `showDialog` for the `AlertDialog` to appear:

```
class AlertWindow  {
  final String title;
  final BuildContext context;

  const AlertWindow({Key key, this.title, this.context});

  void widget(){
           showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(this.title),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: new Text(
                      "OK"
                  )
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  }
```

Working example:

https://dartpad.dev/051f787e1737de84609a390d31c36ee0

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

Comment: I tried your code but the Alert Dialog is still not displayed?

Comment: I dont think the build method is getting called when you do new AlertWindow, can you add a breakpoint and debug it

Comment: Do a `Hot Restart` or re-run of the app after making changes.

Comment: @dev-aentgs did a Hot Restart but no `Alert` yet.

Comment: @PeterHaddad breakpoint inside build function does not hit, not does breakpoint in the constructor of the `AlertWindow` class.

Comment: @MiguelSanchez working example https://dartpad.dev/051f787e1737de84609a390d31c36ee0

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes this example works, mind explaining what was going wrong with the previous examples?

Comment: @MiguelSanchez in the first example, the build method wasnt getting called, just add a print() in the build statement and see if it will print anything

Comment: @PeterHaddad your example or the example that I posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215893/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-miguel-sanchez).